# Get related node by taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, blocks

Let's say I have two content types: Page and News.   Both of them have a field called Tags which is taxonomy term.

Let's say I tag a page and a news item with the term 'celebration'.  When a user goes to the page on the front end website, the user should see related news items on the right side bar.  A news item is related to a page if they both have at least one tag in common.

I tried to set up a news item block, but i don't know how to tell it to show only news items that share at least 1 tag in common with the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use contextual filters and relationships to show related articles?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/how-do-i-use-contextual-filters-and-relationships-to-show-related-articles)

Answer (score 2):

I've used the 2.x version of Similar by Terms in the past, and it is very good, with nice views integration. A D7 version of the 2.x branch is in development at http://drupal.org/node/1270244.

The Apache Solr module can also supply a block of nodes that have similar taxonomy terms based on a Solr database: http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr. Very fast, but not trivial to set up.

Finally, here's a comparison of similar/relevant content block modules: http://drupal.org/node/323329.

Answer (score 1):

I don't this is good form, but it achieved what I wanted.  I created a block then pasted in the php code.

```
<?php

  if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1))) {

        $sql = "
SELECT node.* FROM node
INNER JOIN field_data_field_tags ON field_data_field_tags.entity_id = node.nid
WHERE node.type = 'document'
AND field_data_field_tags.field_tags_tid IN 

                (SELECT field_tags_tid FROM field_data_field_tags
                INNER JOIN node ON node.nid = field_data_field_tags.entity_id
                WHERE node.nid = ".intval(arg(1)).")
        ";

        $result = db_query($sql);
        while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
                echo '<a href="'.url('node/'.$row->nid).'">'.$row->title.'</a>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: useful, also you can remove current node from result by adding `... AND node.nid != ". arg(1) ." ...`

Comment: Does the trick, but not nearly as cleanly as modules like [similarterms](https://drupal.org/project/similarterms). See @jordan's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think that this module can be useful http://drupal.org/project/similarterms

> Similarity is based on the taxonomy terms assigned to content. Blocks
>   are available based on similarity within each of the defined
>   vocabularies for a site as well as a block for similarity within all
>   vocabularies.