# Related nodes based on a shared taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

Using views, how can I find related nodes (across different content types) based on a shared taxonomy?

Let's say I have two content types:

1. Cars
2. Motorcycles

Both share a taxonomy: Colors.

If I have a car node titled "Accord", tagged with the color "Red", and a motorcycle node titled "Sportster", also tagged with the color "Red"... using a views block configured to find similarly tagged nodes, how would I list the Sportster node on the Accord node page?

---

FYI: I'm working on a somewhat locked down Drupal installation. So if this can be accomplished purely with views, and not by relying on additional modules, that would be awesome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get related node by taxonomy term?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9991/get-related-node-by-taxonomy-term)

Comment: @4k4 Preferably, this needs to be done with views, not new modules.