# Create a views block which shows terms from a specific taxonomy vocabulary added to the node

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

If you have a taxonomy called "How to get there" and a restaurant node. When you edit that restaurant node you can select what travel methods you can arrive at that restaurant using. We want to surface this information on the node which is very easily done using display but the taxonomy terms don't have CSS classes for us to target to turn into an icon. I thought of doing this by creating a views block? Or is there a simpler way to render the taxonomy terms on the node with css classes for each one for example this is how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: [This][1] existing stackoverflow drupal question and answer worked for me.


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69426/get-list-of-taxonomy-terms-for-current-node-through-views