# Nodes display links to shared document(s)

Tags: files

### Summary

Nodes display links to shared document(s)

### Example

PDFs to upload only once before I create the workshops:

- Booking Form Primary School
- Booking Form Secondary Schoool
- Risk Assessment for Primary School
- Risk Assessment for Secondary School

Then I would like to be able to be able to create a workshop node using a custom content type and while creating this node, be able to click check boxes of some of the forms above.
When viewing the node of the workshop, for the ticked forms to be displayed as Links to download the PDFs.

This is so that when creating lots of Workshops, I can just tick the boxes for the form downloads to be displayed on each workshop page.

### My Attempt

1. I created a taxonomy called: Forms.
2. For this vocabulary I added a file field: field_form
3. Then I added the terms and uploaded a document for each
4. Then in the Content Type adding a term reference field linking to the vocabulary.
5. **This is where I get stuck.** In the Content Type Display it only shows links to the term page and not the File download.

How would I setup the ability to upload some PDFs and then be able to then create some nodes that display links to these PDFs as downloads?

Comment: If you're on Drupal 8.5, using Media and Entity browser is the way to go, instead of using Taxonomy for PDF files structure. There are more steps to configure it, but it gives superior user experience when creating nodes and choosing files. See a long article here, especially look at the bottom about Entity browser (you can find videos and examples online, make sure it's D8.5) [Managing Media Assets using Core Media in Drupal 8](https://www.webwash.net/managing-media-assets-using-core-media-in-drupal-8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a block views of terms to display the links to term files;
2. add a filter/contextual filter in the view to show only the files of the terms of the current node;
3. set the block to show up on node pages (except node edit pages).

Comment: Thanks Paulo. What is the name of the Contextual Filter that I need?

Comment: Got it. I found this article about displaying the terms associated with a node: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69426/get-list-of-taxonomy-terms-for-current-node-through-views