# How to create links from term to node

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

On the node display I would like to create a list of services but for some of the services, I would like the list element to be displayed as a link to a certain node, and some will not have links.

I tried creating a vocabulary called Services with an additional Link field, but with no luck.

Ideally it would be good to reference the NID, incase the path changes in the future, and display the link URL without the NID as its final path. But if there is a simpler way using final paths, then I am happy with this.

Below is the desired outcome.

Services:
- Website Design <--Linked to node/2
- SEO <-- no link
- Hosting <-- linked to node/4

Answer (score 0):

The module [Special menu items](https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) lets you create menu items that aren't links.

Using Taxonomy doesn't seem like it would do anything to solve this, unless you want a different list of links to show depending on what node it's being displayed on.

So basically you just create a new Menu and add menu items you want in the list. A Block showing the list is automatically created for each new Menu, so you just have to go to Block configuration and place it in a region of your theme to make it appear. On Block configuration you'll also be able to restrict which pages to display the links on, maybe just the one node.

The thing you asked about using NID is concerning Path aliases. You can use the module Global redirect to make the system always output the alias instead of the NID link. With Pathauto you can configure patterns to automatically create path aliases when creating new content.

Comment: The point of using taxonomy was the list will be different depending on which node it is on. e.g. Node1-Web Design & SEO. Node2 - SEO.
So from within the node edit, you can select some boxes, and the correct list/links will be displayed.

Comment: That is a significantly different request than what you originally posted. Please update your question with as much information as is needed to understand the problem. It seems you want to post a list of nodes that share the same Taxonomy terms as the node you're viewing, or just the Taxonomy term is some cases. Is that an accurate description?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the results using a view, following the instructions in the below answer:
[Get list of taxonomy terms for current node through Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69426/get-list-of-taxonomy-terms-for-current-node-through-views#answer-69431)

Then placing this Views block on the node.